# PHP Pagination: How to create a paging link?

Tags: php, pagination

So I am following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm) tutorial. `PHP_SELF` is not working in my case because I am using pagination in a search result page and url itself have variable query string. `REQUEST_URI` is not working because every time it's appending the last url

```
 <?
        if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $base_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }
        if( $page > 0 ) {
            $last = $page - 2;
            echo "<a href = \"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?page = $last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
            echo "<a href = \"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?page = $page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
        }else if( $page == 0 ) {
            echo "<a href = \"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?page = $page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
        }else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit ) {
            $last = $page - 2;
            echo "<a href = \"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?page = $last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
        }

        ?>
```

My URL is generated as:

```
search.php?mode=keyword&keyword=&importer_name=&consignor_name=&description=&bl_date=&categories%5B%5D=0
```

Fields are dynamic.

Comment: Some thing like this echo "<a href = \"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?mode=".$_GET['mode']."&keyword=".$_GET['keyword']."&your_other_attributes= ".$_GET['your_other_attributes']."&page = $last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";

Comment: @ArjanShrestha but entire URL is dynamic hence can't create one

Comment: If URL is dynamic show us how URL is created

Comment: @ArjanShrestha All form fields are pased as `$_GET`

Comment: So you get the query string from the form element. If that is so just use all form elements name in the query string in above code.

Answer (score 0):

For search results I used to create this code:

```
  <?    
        $pager = array(
/*here is some params from MySQL and $_GET*/
'current'=0, // current page num from $_GET
'total' = 200, // Total pages counted based on MySQL query results
);

        $params = $_GET; // do not forget to cleanup and validate GET before using it!

        $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // in my case here is URL generated
        $page = trim(str_replace('//', '/', $page), '/'); // just to be shure

        // Do we need PREV page button?  
        if ($pager['current'] != 0) {
            if (($pager['current'] - 1) == 0) {
                unset($params['page']);
            } else {
                $params['page'] = $pager['current'] - 1;
            }
            $url = trim($page . '?' . http_build_query($params), '?');
            $pervpage = '<li class="previous"><a href="' . $url . '">&lt;</a></li>';
        }
        // Do we need NEXT page button?  
        if ($pager['current'] != ($pager['total'] - 1)) {
            $params['page'] = $pager['current'] + 1;
            $url = trim($page . '?' . http_build_query($params), '?');
            $nextpage = '<li class="next"><a href="' . $url . '">&gt;</a></li>';
        }

        // Lets create 2 buttins fo pages before current and 2 buttons for pages after current

        $start = $pager['current'] - 2 >= 0 ? $pager['current'] - 2 : 0;
        $end = $pager['current'] + 3 <= $pager['total'] ? $pager['current'] + 3 : $pager['total'];

        if ($end - $start <= 4) {
            if ($end == $pager['total']) {
                $start = $pager['total'] - 5 >= 0 ? $pager['total'] - 5 : 0;
            }
            if ($start == 0) {
                $end = $pager['total'] >= 5 ? 5 : $pager['total'];
            }
        }
        $pager['pages'] = $pervpage;
        for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
            if ($i == $pager['current']) {
                $pager['pages'] .= '<li><span>' . ($i + 1) . '</span></li>';
            } else {
                if ($i == 0) {
                    unset($params['page']);
                } else {
                    $params['page'] = $i;
                }
                $url = trim($page . '?' . http_build_query($params), '?');
                $pager['pages'] .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '" >' . ($i + 1 == 0 ? "" : $i + 1) . '</a> </li>';
            }
        }
        $pager['pages'] .= $nextpage;
        // And we almost ready to output results
        $pager['pages'] = str_replace('?&', '?', $pager['pages']);
        // Now we can output results
        echo $pager['pages'];
    ?>
```

I think it might be optimized. But for now it's doing the job just fine

Answer (score 0):

- **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** contains the entire URI including the query ($_GET parameters).
- You are adding new parameter each time the request is issued.
- So, try to extract the **script URI** instead (see example below).

  ```
  <?php
      // Display what we have got on input
      echo "<h3>\$_GET parameters received:</h3>";
      if (count($_GET)<1) {
          echo "NONE<br />";
      } else foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v) {
          echo "\$_GET[$k]=$v<br />";
      }

      echo "<h3>Link created:</h3>";

      // Get URI elements and create script URI
      $prot = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) && (strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'ON')) ? 'https' : 'http';
      $script_url  = $prot . '://' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . ':' . getenv('SERVER_PORT') . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
      // Collect parameters
      $query = '';
      $pagenum = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : -1;
      foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v) {
          if (strtolower($k)=='page') continue; // skip 'page' parameter
          $query .= "&$k=$v";
      }
      // Create link
      $pagenum++;
      $link = $script_url . '?page=' . $pagenum . $query ;
      echo "\$link=$link<br />";
      echo "<a href=\"$link\">link</a><br />";
  ?>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The use of $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] may solve your problem if the query string is being produced dynamically... Following code my help your problem

```
if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}else{
$query_string = "";
}
echo "<a href = \"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}?".$query_string."&page = $last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
```